# Spring Data - most often solutions for paging and sorting tables

Tags: spring, sorting, paging

I searching for most often solutions for paging and sorting in Spring projects. I found couple of .js libraries, but I have implemented paging table by passing param from jsp to repository and invokes it by:

users.jsp

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <th><a href="<c:out value="?page=${pageNumber}&sort=name&order=asc" />">Imię</a></th>
            <th><a href="<c:out value="?page=${pageNumber}&sort=lastname&order=asc" />">Nazwisko</a></th>
            <th><a href="<c:out value="?page=${pageNumber}&sort=login&order=asc" />">Login</a></th>
            <th><a href="<c:out value="?page=${pageNumber}&sort=email&order=asc" />">Email</a></th>
            <th><a href="<c:out value="?page=${pageNumber}&sort=enabled&order=asc" />">Aktywny</a></th>
            <th><a href="<c:out value="?page=${pageNumber}&sort=created&order=asc" />">Data utworzenia</a></th>
            <th><a href="<c:out value="?page=${pageNumber}&sort=logged&order=asc" />">Ostatnio zalogowany</a></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${user.firstName}</td>
                        <td>${user.lastName}</td>
                        <td>${user.login}</td>
                        <td>${user.email}</td>
                        <td>${user.enabled}</td>
                        <td>${user.createDate}</td>
                        <td>${user.loginDate}</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="<c:url value="/users/${user.userID}/edit" />">Edytuj</a></td>
                        <td><a onclick="return confirm('Czy aby napewno chcesz usunąć?')" class="btn btn-danger" href="<c:url value="/users/${user.userID}/delete" />">Usuń</a></td>
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

UserController.java

```
   @RequestMapping
    public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer pageNumber, @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) String sort, @RequestParam(value = "order", required = false) String order, Model model) {

        Sort sorting;
        pageNumber = (pageNumber == null) ? 1 : pageNumber;

        if (sort == null || sort.isEmpty()) {
            sorting = new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "firstName"));
            model.addAttribute("order", "asc");
        } else {
            if (order.equals("asc")) {
                sorting = new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, sort));
                model.addAttribute("order", "desc");
            } else {
                sorting = new Sort(new Order(Direction.DESC, sort));
                model.addAttribute("order", "asc");
            }
        }


        Page<User> page = userService.getAllUsers(pageNumber, sorting);

        model.addAttribute("users", page.getContent());

        return "users";
    }
```

And my UserService.java extending from JpaRepository:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "first_name"));
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE, sort);
```

This method works.. but if I want sort this table it will be needed passing 2 more parametres like sort and order. It must be better way do this, some one could show me example to paging and sorting by Spring Data and .jsp?

Comment: Check out `PagingAndSortingRepository` and Example 4 from  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

Comment: If you want something to be paged and sorted, I don't see how you could do it without passing parameters telling which sort criterion to use, which direction, and which page you want. What's so bad or strange about it?

Comment: @JB Nizet Ok, but can you tell me a way to do it in elegant way. The way I was doing it earilier: passing from .jsp two params, get it in controller (switching order if neccessary), pass them to service method where are included to **PageRequest** but in my opinion it is far from good programing practices, beacuse when I try implement search method it's genrated many repeated code in other controller method..

Comment: Go to codereview.stackexchange.com, post your code there, and ask for improvements.

Comment: There is not *nearly* enough code in this question to formulate an answer on SO or CR

Comment: I added more code to explain.